# Does a wind "picking up" have the same meaning as "getting strong"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> The wind is getting strong.

Can I also say the quoted sentence:

> The wind is **picking up**

Is it right to say it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is one of the ways to say that the wind is getting stronger or increased in its pace or intensity.

> *The wind always picks up in the evening* - [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pick-up)

Weather forecast often uses the phrase. [Check the title here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1axcigd9idc)